# Constructing paginated API response for GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, api

How can I return a paginated GeoJSON payload from an API, including page information?

The pagination applies to the number of features in a feature collection.  If the standards specify pagination, links to the details would be useful. As far as I know the pagination for JSON/GeoJSON is not specified in specs e.g.

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 (geojson)
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8142 (geojsons)

For example, consider these two options.  The first option is to add a "pages" data-structure to the GeoJSON, e.g.

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-123.3948022, 41.254734],
                    [-123.3948022, 41.2537144],
                    [-123.3907336, 41.2537144],
                    [-123.3907336, 41.254734],
                    [-123.3948022, 41.254734]
                ]
            ],
            "type": "Polygon"
        },
        "properties": {
            "level": 0
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }, {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-123.3907336, 41.254734],
                    [-123.3907336, 41.2537144],
                    [-123.3893774, 41.2537144],
                    [-123.3893774, 41.254734],
                    [-123.3907336, 41.254734]
                ]
            ],
            "type": "Polygon"
        },
        "properties": {
            "level": 2
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    }],
    "pages": {
        "next": {
            "limit": 2,
            "offset": 2
        },
        "page": {
            "limit": 2,
            "offset": 0
        },
        "prev": null
    }
}
```

The second option creates a nested JSON payload with separate geojson and pages fields, i.e. the pseudo-JSON is like:

```json
{
  "geojson": { ... },
  "pages": {
    "next": {
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 2
    },
    "page": {
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "prev": null
  }
}
```

Or similarly, but without the extra "pages" nesting:

```json
{
  "geojson": { ... },
  "next": {
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 2
  },
  "page": {
        "limit": 2,
        "offset": 0
  },
  "prev": null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look at the [OGC Features API](https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features) (aka WFS3) which covers this great detail.

[Example 10 of the standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/17-069r3/17-069r3.html#_response_6) covers `offsets` which seems to be what you want.

If you need a working example of the standard GeoServer has an e[xperimental extension](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.17.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-wfs3-plugin.zip) you can add.

Comment: Version 1.0.1 of the standard has `offset` in Example 11: https://docs.ogc.org/is/17-069r4/17-069r4.html#fc-response